# Error opening 5.3 model in 6 -(of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)

Tags: netlogo

When trying to open a 5.3 model, it opens and runs correctly. But if that model is saved in 6.0, when re-opening the model it gives the error code:

```
Netlogo can't open the model "Model location"

List(Infected) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon).
```

"infected" is a possible attribute for turtle-owned variables but no where in the model does anything use the term with caps "Infected".

Any advice? There are no ?, $, or nobody in the model. Is this a problem with anonymous procedures?

Comment: Can you post the model? If you would prefer to receive support without sharing the model publicly you can email bugs -at- ccl -dot- northwestern -dot- edu.

Comment: do you use any extensions? I had a similar issue and it was because I was invoking the rngs extension, which was built for netlogo version 4 something. I never found a work around though, I'm just sticking with 5.3 until I need to start a new model